# Full Height Image in Responsive Div split 50%

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is split 50% between text and an image. i would like the image on the right to always be the same height as the text, I have been following numerous posts this morning but cannot seem to get this to work.

You can see an example of the page here:
http://pagedev.co.uk/bowmite/test/electrical.html

I think I am almost there, you can see the orange background which shows the base of the div.. the image just needs to fit down to this and overflow where needed...

My html is:

```
<div class="split-wrapper">
                        <div class="split-left">
                            <p>Our focus is quality, pure and simple. We strive to retain our high standards and reputation whilst learning from each successful high quality installation. Implementating control procedures within an ever changing market place has been key to our success.</p>
                            <p>You will find our site teams are efficiently supervised with high levels of management availability and client liaison. We enjoy long term relationships with many of our clients, thanks to our comprehensive understanding of quality.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="split-right">
                            <img class="right-align-image" src="images/electrical-bottom.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My Css is:

```
.split-wrapper  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#ff6600;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display:inline-block;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}

.split-left {
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;

    background-color:#ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.split-right    {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:hidden;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.split-right img    {
    width:;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I believe you will need to use jQuery for that.

Comment: set parent `height:100%` and image `height:100%, width:auto` but some part of the image will get hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CSS table layout for the split columns and a background image for the right.

Support for [CSS tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and [CSS3 background-size](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) is pretty decent and its logical and easy to work with. Furthermore, its naturally flexible (responsive) and can easily be changed with media-queries when the viewport is too small for a split layout.

```
.split {
    display:table;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:50px;
}
.split .col {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%; padding:30px;
}
.split .imgbg {
    background: url(http://pagedev.co.uk/bowmite/test/images/electrical-bottom.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .split {
        display:block;
    }
    .split .col {
        display:block;
        width:auto;
    }
    .split .imgbg {
        height:100px;
    }
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/fc4coukr/
(make sure you resize it)

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is telling the exactly width you want... If you are going to use media-queries you can say: for this resolution, i want this image with this width and this height.

Another solution is using the image like a background, and telling via css to cover all the container:

```
.split-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: url('../images/electrical-bottom.jpg');
background-size: cover;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 4px;
```

}

The problem is that maybe the photo isn't as you would like to.

Try to play with the [background-size properties](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.split-right img').height($('.split-left').outerHeight());
});
```

The `split-left` div has a height of `393px` with all the text inside it, including borders, and the above jQuery code assigns that height to the image. This will work even if you change the length of the text inside the `split-left` div.

Secondly, you will need to add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.split-right img {
     width: //100% or auto;
}
```

You will need to choose between `100%` or `auto` for the `width` of the image. If you choose `100%`, the image will appear squashed and if you choose `auto`, only a small part of the image will be visible.

But if you're adamant on using CSS, what you can do is that you can remove the image from inside the `split-right` div and instead use that image as a `background-image` on the `.split-wrapper` div like this:

```
.split-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://pagedev.co.uk/bowmite/test/images/electrical-bottom.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```